# Android shadowed bottom border

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I want to know can I draw this type of line (Shadowed line) for my bottom border any help???

Comment: if you can see above the question i uploaded the Image. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `9 patch` of the same image, mark the expandable area as everything above this border, and set this `9 patch` as the background of the view to which you want to have this border.

You could also, create a `LinearLayout` with required height (2-3 dp?) and use this as the background image. Put this layout below the view for which you want this border.